# Allowing users to select different custom markers in google maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I know the code that lets you use your own custom markers for google maps on iOS and Android but I am looking to see how I can have a menu for the different types of markers people want to you. I see many google map apps having different types of markers but I wonder how they let this happen, anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

Custom markers are just PNG image files.  All you need to do is create an image picker of the available icon files you want to allow users to use; and then assign the target marker object icon property to use that image file.

In one of my apps I have a dictionary of UIImage with a string ID as the key.  When I assign an icon to a marker all I need to do is:
myMarker.icon = [myIconDict objectForKey:selectedIconId];

Comment: How exactly do I create the image picker?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution for icon image picker is probably a UITableView. The built in UITableViewCell already has an imageview and a text label.  Set the ImageView to the icon image, and the text to some table.